# Can't see images and buttons while iOS app is running - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

When I'm trying to run my app (doesn't matter is this virtual machine or my real phone) I can't see images and buttons (button is working correctly when I'm clicking where it supposed to be, but he's just not showing up).

Here's log from my debug window:

> 2018-11-18 21:48:48.440964+0100 Dicee[10171:751257] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

This is what it should looks like:

[image]

And this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit/SceneKit, or UIKit, to setup the UI?

Comment: How can I check that? Sorry for asking, but now I'm just following some udemy instructor and not sure what's going on

Comment: Ok, lets look at the icon at the top. Did you drag-and-drop that, or did you use some code to add it in?

Comment: Dragged and dropped - from library to main.storyboard, and with pressed ctrl from storyboard to assistant editor to make variable and method

Comment: Ok, so UIKit. Is the green background also an image from the storyboard, or is it a background of some sort.

Comment: It's an image from storyboard - I think I know what's the reason, images are probably in wrong order, so background image is covering the others. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for double post but I just found a reason: pictures were in wrong order - I have edited the background image after I put the other images and button so it all got covered by background image. Solution was to move to the top background image in document outline.
Hope that will help newbies like me ;)